# Apache Spark Issue with Py4JJavaError while code execution

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

No matter what I do I can't get past this error while running Apache spark.
I am running it through Jupyter Notebook which is pointing to Anaconda environment.

I am new to spark learning and I have checked so many blogs to fix this error but nothing helped.

any help is appreciated to fix it.
I am running java 8.

Code I am running :

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
lines=sc.textFile("C:/User/PG186028/Spark.txt")
lines.count()
```

error generated after  lines.count():

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-c98a4dbe0cd9> in <module>()
----> 1 files.count()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py in count(self)
   1051         3
   1052         """
-> 1053         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
   1054 
   1055     def stats(self):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py in sum(self)
   1042         6.0
   1043         """
-> 1044         return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
   1045 
   1046     def count(self):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py in fold(self, zeroValue, op)
    913         # zeroValue provided to each partition is unique from the one provided
    914         # to the final reduce call
--> 915         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
    916         return reduce(op, vals, zeroValue)
    917 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py in collect(self)
    812         """
    813         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 814             sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    815         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    816 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py in _jrdd(self)
   2472                                       self._jrdd_deserializer, profiler)
   2473         python_rdd = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD(self._prev_jrdd.rdd(), wrapped_func,
-> 2474                                              self.preservesPartitioning)
   2475         self._jrdd_val = python_rdd.asJavaRDD()
   2476 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1523         answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1524         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1525             answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
   1526 
   1527         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    330                 raise Py4JError(
    331                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
--> 332                     format(target_id, ".", name, value))
    333         else:
    334             raise Py4JError(

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD([class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, class org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonFunction, class java.lang.Boolean]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:179)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:196)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:237)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: what's the code generating the error?

Comment: @mtoto : updated it in Question